# how to download ubuntu from the official site through BitTorrent download

Tags: downloads

i want to download ubuntu. is it possible to download ubuntu from the official website through BitTorrent download. i only see direct download. my connection is not stable so i cant download direct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on alternative downloads page (for example [this](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)), you find a link to download the torrent file.

Answer (score 2):

If you browse the releases site for the version / flavour you need, you'll find torrent files in each folder.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/